# Store all the keys of a JSON object in a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I get from the server strings like the following:

```
{"Point Ref":[15629989,564646414,65494949],
"Effective Date":["2008-03-03","2010-12-14","2004-10-01"],
"Identifier":["EM","EM","SC"],"Status":["FI","SI","XC"]}"
```

which I convert to `JSON` with:

```
var jsonResponse = jQuery.parseJSON(xmlHttp.responseText.trim());
```

Until here everything is fine: I can loop through `jsonResponse` and do my stuff. However I can't find an easy quick way to have immediately all the key in one `array`.

Basically, is there anything else other than this:

```
var keys = new Array();
var n = 0
for (var i in jsonResponse){
    keys[n] = i
    n ++
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: For future reference, the strings you get from the server are `JSON` and you parse them into javascript objects.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [Object.keys](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CC8QFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen-US%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FObject%2Fkeys&ei=M9EIUr_jMoOi0QX29oCgDA&usg=AFQjCNG8ofWu2NG52M-pj2pcIH1ewD2FJQ&bvm=bv.50500085,d.d2k):

```
var keys = Object.keys(jsonResponse);
```

Comment: Well, this is nothing to do with JSON.  As soon as you call `parseJSON` you have a JavaScript `Object` to work with.

Comment: I see thanks, but now I remember that I tried that already. In fact I have posted the way I get and convert my JSON cause I think the issue is in there

Comment: He's probably using ie < 9. Add the polyfill: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution using [array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
//minified polyfill for old browsers:
if (!Array.prototype.map) { Array.prototype.map = function (e, t) { var n, r, i; if (this == null) { throw new TypeError(" this is null or not defined") } var s = Object(this); var o = s.length >>> 0; if (typeof e !== "function") { throw new TypeError(e + " is not a function") } if (t) { n = t } r = new Array(o); i = 0; while (i < o) { var u, a; if (i in s) { u = s[i]; a = e.call(n, u, i, s); r[i] = a } i++ } return r } }

var keys = jsonResponse.map(function(v, k) { return k; });
```

Comment: @nigmastar Then you need to include the polyfill in the link. I\ll update the code.